# solr server stops indexing after some records

Tags: django, solr, solrcloud

I have solr installed on AWS cloud, which is not able to complete my indexing.
I have similar DB and solr on my local system where indexing runs fine and I can search all data.
I have monitored memory consumption , heap size on AWS while indexing is running. Nothing seems unusual.

```
python manage.py rebuild_index --noinput -b 1000 --workers 4
```

This command shows that 168252 records will be indexed while indexing stops at 164252 and it never completes.
On local it completes all records indexing.
What is the reason for this unusual behaviour ?

Comment: Do you have duplicate values for your unique key field? In that case later documents will overwrite those that have been added previously.

Comment: But then it should not work on local solr as well..

Comment: Have you made sure the schema is the same, including the different schema types? If a uniqueKey field is an integer on one server and a string on the other, that may give you different behaviour. Have you tried diffing the ids indexed to both servers to see where the difference is?

Comment: It's hard to tell, but I would start by using a (much) smaller file in your AWS installation and see if that completes successfully.